# Use eleventy to output markdown format?

Tags: eleventy

Is it possible to change the layouts such that eleventy generate a set of markdown format files?

I have a list of authors from a library catalogue which I want to continue edit them to make a single page for each of the author. So I want to generate a markdown template for each record first, then I will continue edit these one by one.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? You want to create one markdown file for each author, but don't include them in the output until their complete? That's just a matter of adding a field in your frontmatter (like `draft: true`) and using that to filter your collections. Or do you want to output markdown text directly on your site?

Comment: These pages will become base for further editing. Some of them will be copied into the content directories and add more information for generated the html pages. The author's pages will have two sections, one is basic just generated from the list, the other will have more details written by librarian or patrons.

Comment: I still don't understand what problem you're trying to solve? You want to create some markdown files? What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: After some try I understand SSG is not a good choice. Because they dont care about line breaks. Python or js is better choice. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eleventy and templating to generate a variety of file types, including Markdown. Essentially, if you have text and want to use templating languages to generate it, Eleventy can do that.

For example, let's say you have a [global data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global/) containing fruit names. This could also be an array of objects, but for simplicity let's just use names for now. In your case, this could be an array of objects for each author.

```js
// _data/fruits.js
module.exports = [
    'Apples',
    'Bananas',
    'Oranges',
    'Pears',
]
```

You want to create a Markdown page for each fruit with a little description. In this example, I'll be using [Nunjucks](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/nunjucks/) but this could be adapted to any templating language supported by Eleventy.

In `fruits.md.njk` (name doesn't matter):

```
---
pagination:
  data: fruits
  size: 1
  alias: fruit

permalink: 'fruits/{{ fruit | slug }}.md'
---
--- {# We can even define front-matter that will appear in the output #}
layout: content
---
# About {{ fruit }}

{# Use whatever markdown syntax you want #}
{{ fruit }} are _very_ **delicious**.

`Buy {{ fruit }} here!`
```

In this template, we are using [pagination](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/) to create individual pages for each item in the `fruits` array ([paging global data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/#paginate-a-global-or-local-data-file)). We define a `permalink` to output a `.md` file, and the rest of the file is just normal Markdown, with added templating tags. You can use all of the regularly available Nunjucks/other templating tags, such as loops, macros, or inheritance.

You can extend these ideas to generate other things, like Javascript files, JSON files, YAML files, XML, or any file that's just text. Nothing is stopping you from templating things that aren't HTML.

The output of the above template is:

```
--- 
layout: content
---
# About Apples


Apples are _very_ **delicious**.

`Buy Apples here!`
```